# Objective C number keypad, custom comma button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to add a comma button on a number keypad that has previous, next and done buttons, so that it looks like this :

[image: Orange button is the one I'm trying to make work]

Problem is, that the orange button does not respond to taps. Actually if I moved it above the "7" button and tapped it, the 7 would be tapped. So my orange button may be shown above the keyboard, but it's reacting to taps as if it were below.

Here is an abstract of my code :

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   UIView *inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, screenWidth, 40.0)];
   // 3 buttons on top
   UIView *topToolbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, screenWidth, 40.0)];
   [topToolbar addSubview:self.inputPrevButton];
   [topToolbar addSubview:self.inputNextButton];
   [topToolbar addSubview:self.inputDoneButton];
   [inputAccessoryView addSubview:topToolbar];
   // Comma button
   UIButton *commaButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [commaButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 204, 105, 52)];
   [commaButton setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [commaButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addComma) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [commaButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

   [inputAccessoryView addSubview:commaButton];
   // Useless, but tried anyway
   [inputAccessoryView bringSubviewToFront:commaButton];

   [textField setInputAccessoryView:self.inputAccessoryView];
 }
```

All I know is that I should not be doing [this](http://myviewonit.blogspot.com/2010/08/iphones-numeric-pad-keyboard-with-dot.html) (which is actually not working), so what should I do ?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not set the text field's keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`. Then you get a period or comma as appropriate based on the user's locale. No need to add a custom button.

Comment: Also, you should set the `inputAccessoryView` once when you create the text field. Don't do it every time the text field gains focus.

Comment: I obviously didn't my homework properly, I didn't know `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` existed. Thanks for the other comment too. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) in the comments : no need to add a custom comma as a keybord with the comma exists : `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`, or in the storyboard :

[image: choose decimal pad in storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextField* tf = TEXTFIELDNAME;
tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```